# Directory Listing

Tags: html, directory

Ok, so I have a directory and a file on my server in my public_html folder .

The directory name is : sample
And the file name is : index.html

Inside the sub-directory sample there is another file called home.html

Now , I want my home.html to refer to its parent directory index.html .
But , for that I have to put my index.html file into the sub-directory sample , which I do not want .

So , please tell me how to do it ! 
I do not want to redirect , I want a link on my home.html file that refers to index.html in my parent directory .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to link to parent directory just write:

```
<a href="../index.html">text</a>
```